# I always use "concurrently" for mern project (nodejs & reactjs) but now I can't able to install concurrently

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern

PS E:\test\react_express_starter> npm i concurrently

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...Kz5ckaK\nf5E8uavgOU9d'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Masum\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-12-29T16_26_15_224Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

Clearing npm cache should solve the issue:

`npm cache clean --force`